# Given $0<\lambda<1.$ Prove that if all $x,y>0,$ $f(x+y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y),$ then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> **Question**: Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $0<\lambda<1.$ Prove that if all $x,y>0,$ $$f(x+y) = \lambda f(x)
>  + (1-\lambda)f(y),$$ then $f$ is a constant function.

My attempt:

Fix $x,y>0.$
Note that 
$$f(2x)=f(x)$$
and 
$$f(2y) = f(y).$$
Also,
$$f(2x+y) = \lambda f(2x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) =  f(x+y).$$
Also, 
$$f(2x+y) = f(x+(x+y)) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(x+y).$$
Since $\lambda\neq 0,$ so we have 
$$f(x) = f(x+y).$$
By symmetry, we also have 
$$f(y) = f(x+y).$$
So 
$$f(x)=f(y).$$
So $f$ is a constant function.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: How did you get $f(x)=f(x+y)$?

Comment: @AlexR.: Edited.

Comment: It looks like your proof shows the function must be constant *whenever* your function has this property (for all $x$, $y >0$) even *without* the measurability hypothesis or the conditions on $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct.

You really do not need this  $$f(2x+y) = f(x+(x+y)) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(x+y).$$

because you already have $$f(x)=f(x+y)$$

Use symmetry to to show $$f(y)=f(x+y)$$

Thus f(x)=f(y).
I could not find a better way to do it. If we assume differentiability then  we  can easily show $f'(x)=0.$

Comment: How do I obtain $f(x) = f(x+y)$ without $f(2x+y) = f(x+(x+y)) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(x+y)?$